# How to configure gitolite for a single domain on Plesk

Tags: git, cross-domain, centos, plesk, gitolite

How to configure the gitolite on a plesk panel single domain.

When I use a /bin/bash user created by plesk, the home folder becomes /var/www/vhosts/{user}/

Then after install gitolite there, the user still not using the $HOME/bin/ folder to find the gitolite binary, and uses the system binary, so always when I try to clone the gitolite-admin come's a empty directory.

How to configure the plesk ssh domain user to use the $HOME/bin folder to access the gitolite repo and it binaries?

I'm using CentOS 5 with Plesk 10.0.1

Thanks.

Comment: Your question heading and text don't match. Are you using gitosis, or gitolite? If you have the choice, Gitolite should be preferred.

Comment: Sorry, I fixed the question, its about the gitolite only.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I will assume that you are using some variables like:

```
Domain: gartz.com.br 
Username: gartz
```

Go in your plesk panel and add SSH /bin/bash access to the user that you wan't to install gitolite repositorie.

Now SSH login your server as **root** privileges. And type `su - gartz` you are now in your user bash.

Type `pwd` it will show your `${HOME}` like: `/var/www/vhosts/gartz.com.br/`

go back to super user and add privileges to user can write your own home folder and add a git folder:

```
$ chown gartz:psacln /var/www/vhosts/gartz.com.br/
$ su - gartz
$ mkdir git
```

Now you have this: `/var/www/vhosts/gartz.com.br/git`

Download your gitolite to the git folder, then add a user with will have access to your git repositories only, like using suffix or preffix git: `adduser gartz.git`

Edit your passwd file to your git user have the same ids from the normal user and change the home to the correct git folder. (you will need root privileges again)

```
$ cat /etc/passwd | grep gartz
```

It will show something like this:

```
gartz:x:10004:2524::/var/www/vhosts/gartz.com.br:/bin/bash
```

Now edit your other user `gartz.git` to be like this:

```
gartz.git:x:10004:2524::/var/www/vhosts/gartz.com.br/git:/bin/bash
```

Add `.ssh` folder with authorized_keys for your rsa key. Then login your shell using your account like `gartz.git` install your gitolite now.

```
$ git clone git://github.com/sitaramc/gitolite
$ cd gitolite/src
$ ./gl-easy-install -q gitolite gitserver sitaram
```

Go to your own computer and clone your gitolite-admin:

```
$ git clone gartz.git@gartz.com.br:gitolite-admin
```

Change your config file, add your keys and repos, commit and push.

You can do this for any domain you want. For more info installing git http://progit.org/book/ch4-8.html

Answer (score 0):

I used the Plesk panel to add a ssh user access to the disired domain, like:

{SSH_USER} = my domain ssh username

SO in my $HOME I have created a folder called $HOME/git and give it permissions, then create a alias user called {SSH_USER}.git that use the same UID/GID from user {SSH_USER}.

```
/var/www/vhosts/<domain>/# mkdir git
```

If you are logged as ROOT change the permission to your {SSH_USER}:psacln

```
# chown -R {SSH_USER}:psacln ./git
```

Now using your root account create a new user called {SSH_USER}.git where the home folder is the git folder that you already created.

Find your uid and gid:

```
# id
uid=10004({SSH_USER}) gid=2524(psacln) groups=2524(psacln)
```

Now create your new user:

```
# sudo adduser {SSH_USER}.git -d /var/www/vhosts/<domain>/git -g 2524 -u 10004
```

Login as {SSH_USER}.git

```
# su - {SSH_USER}.git
```

Install your gitolite. Everything will works.

When you try to login a domain git you need to type:

```
git clone {SSH_USER}.git@<domain>:<repo_name>
```

You can do this for any domain in your server, having a single gitolite administration for the domains.

Comment: You need to add the user with .git suffix using `adduser` command, then you will have 2 users like:
gartz
gartz.git
in the file /etc/passwd you need to make gartz and gartz.git have the same ID for user and group. they will be alias. Change the home from gartz.git to /var/www/vhosts/domain/git
Now in the git folder you can install your gitolite.
At the end you will login the gitolite like: gartz.git@domain.xxx:gitolite_admin clone it, do your permissions.