# Setup Git on Plesk (Debian)

Tags: git, ubuntu, plesk, gitolite

I have installed git on my Ubuntu server running Plesk, but i have tried to follow following method to setup:
[How to configure gitolite for a single domain on Plesk](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4829444/how-to-configure-gitolite-for-a-single-domain-on-plesk/)

But unfortunately the adduser function is not functional (does not fit adduser syntax).

Can anybody tell me if there is another method or what the correction is to the adduser line?

Answer (score 0):

Try this, or simply read the manpage for advice

```
sudo adduser --home /var/www/vhosts/[domain]/git  --uid 10004 --gid 2524 [SSH_USER].git
```

Comment: @CharlesB I was a bit too fast with my post, i actually already tried that and got following error:

`adduser: Please enter a username matching the regular expression configured
via the NAME_REGEX configuration variable.  Use the `--force-badname'
option to relax this check or reconfigure NAME_REGEX.`

Comment: @JavaCake You dialed the wrong number I'm not the answer's author, just edited it :)

Comment: @CharlesB woopsie.. Im new here, so i need to get used to how the identify who wrote what :)

Comment: the above comment was to you :)

Comment: @JavaCake Why don't you just use '--force-badname' then? '[SSH_USER].git' is quite a queer UNIX username, and the system's just trying to tell you that you probably mistyped something.